# Added placeholder text to input element in CSHTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm currently writing an ASP.Net MVC application

I've successfully made an input box in CSHTML.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Test, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })
```

I now want to take the content of a string from the controller and add is as placeholder text. I've tried the following

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Test, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Test) } })
```

But that set the placeholder like so: `placeholder=""`
If I instead use `@Html.DisplayNameFor` it sets the placeholder to the variable's name `Test`, but I want the actual string content. I'm aware that one can use the Viewbag to pass text to the view, but there must be a way of doing it this way.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try changing `placeholder = @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Test) ` with `placeholder = Model.Test`.

Comment: That gives the following error:
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' 

System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model.get returned null.

Comment: In your controller, make sure you are passing an instance of the model to your view.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `@Html.DisplayFor()` as a placeholder but you can use `Html.DisplayNameFor()`.

**Example:**

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Test, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Your Place Holder" } })
```

OR

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Test, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Test) } })
```

Comment: But that's not what I want, though. That would set the placeholder to a string hardcoded in the cshtml file. What I want is to put the content of a string variable in the placeholder attribute.

Comment: May  be you look for second option.

Comment: That sets the placeholder to the variable's name not the string the variable contains.

Comment: do you need the return value of Model.Test as a placeholder?

Comment: Then use placeholder = Model.Test??""

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the [Display (name="Your Text")] attribute in the propriety of the model like this:

```
[Display (Name="Name Of Client:")]
Public string Name {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a Property in your Model which you are passing to view.

Assign the string into that property.

```
Model.SomeName= YourVariableName;
```

Then Try Like This :-

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Test, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = @Model.SomeName }
```